# Embedded bone tool in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am creating a ragdoll game without gravity and with constraints, I want to use the bone tool in flash as3.Is it possible to embedded in a bone tool in Actionscript 3? I can't find a good source in google. Please help guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use another physics engine that you just include through actionscript, like [Box2D](http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect that the Bone tool just exports plain *animations*, so the inverse kinematics are not actually accessible from the Flash Player.

**CORRECTED:** I was actually wrong: [Manipulating springs of an inverse kinematics bone for animations](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flcs5_features_ik.html). I'm sticking with my recommendation that you use a physics engine, though.

Comment: Box2D is a package, you can download it, and there are many tutorials online (google "flash box2d tutorial". The built-in IK works like an actionscript library. I'd suggest you follow the tutorial, are you using the Flash CS5 IDE?

Comment: Then my suggestion is that follow the tutorial I linked in my answer, it is an example of how to control the IK (bones) from AS3.